# Is it possible to say "환영드립니다"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

To say "congratulations," it's possible to say 축하합니다 or 축하드립니다, the latter being more polite.

Is it possible to say 환영드립니다 instead of 환영합니다? If not, why not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68252/discussion-on-question-by-topo-morto-is-it-possible-to-say--).

Comment: 환영드립니다가 잘못된 표현 이긴 합니다만, 원어민이라면 누구나 알아들을 겁니다.

Answer (score 2):

‘환영하다’는 ‘축하하다’와 달리 ‘행복하다’나 ‘기뻐하다’처럼 행위가 아닌 상태를 나타내는 말이기 때문에 행위를 강조하는 ‘-드립니다’가 접사로 쓰이지 않습니다.

---

‘드린다’를 ‘준다’는 뜻 대신 공손함을 더하는 말로 쓰기도 합니다.

제가 많이 찾아봤는데 믿을 만한 레퍼런스는 `표준국어대사전`에 나와 있는 이것뿐이네요.

> -드리다07
>
> 「접사」
>
> ((몇몇 명사 뒤에 붙어))
>
> ‘공손한 행위’의 뜻을 더하고 동사를 만드는 접미사.
>
> ¶ 공양드리다/불공드리다/말씀드리다.

그래서, 실전에서 이 용법을 많이 써 온 사람 중 한 명으로서 더 구체적인 규칙을 직접 추론해 봤습니다.

두 가지 조건으로 요약했습니다.

---

### 1. 다른 대상과 상호작용하는 **행위**를 명사로 나타냅니다.

- 예를 들어 ‘축하’, ‘인사’, ‘방문’ 등 주로 커뮤니케이션하기 위한 행동들이요. ‘환영’은 굳이 쓰려면 쓸 수는 있을 것 같긴 한데 대단히 어색한 표현이에요. 왜냐하면 ‘환영하다’의 ‘환영’은 보통 외적인 행위(동적인 것)가 아니라 마음의 상태(정적인 것)이기 때문입니다.
- 또다른 특징: 이 명사는 보통 한자어가 됩니다. 소위 순우리말은 불규칙성이 있어서 이 용법이 잘 적용되지 않습니다.

---

더 많은 예시:

- '-드리다'형으로 쓸 수 **있는** '-하다' 표현: Verbs used when a person communicates with one another or reacts to one another.

  > 축하하다, 인사하다, 방문하다, 감사하다, 소개하다, 질문하다, 답변하다, 연락하다, 당부하다, 부탁하다, 기도하다, 공양하다, 불공하다
- '-드리다'형으로 쓸 수 **있을 것도 같은** '-하다' 표현: These would be grammatically fine, in a sense, though I never hear those words spoken 'politely'.

  > 저주하다, 비난하다, 비판하다, 매도하다, 징벌하다, 처벌하다
- '-드리다'형으로 쓸 수 **없는** '-하다' 표현 (1): Because these feel adjective, not verb.

  > 환영하다, 행복하다, 비통하다, 어색하다, 분노하다
- '-드리다'형으로 쓸 수 **없는** '-하다' 표현 (2): Verbs, but the subject(speaker) has nothing to do with other people.

  > 준비하다, 공부하다, 명상하다

---

### 2. ‘을, 를, 이, 가, 의, ...’ 같은 조사를 해당 명사에 덧붙이지 않고 띄어쓰기 없이 ‘드립니다’로 연결합니다.

- 이 ‘드립니다’는 ‘준다’의 뜻이 아니라 ‘한다’의 높임말일 뿐이어서 ‘무엇을 드린다’처럼 띄어쓰기 없이 접미사로 쓰이는 것 같습니다.

  > 축하드린다, 인사드린다, 방문드린다, 감사드린다, 소개드린다, 질문드린다, 답변드린다, 연락드린다, 당부드린다, 부탁드린다, 기도드린다, 공양드린다, 불공드린다

---

이상입니다.

Comment: 여기에서의 '-하다'나 '-드리다' 접사는 한국어가 외래어를 받아들여서 그것을 한국어 형식으로 적응시키기 위한 일종의 어댑터 패턴(?)이라고도 생각합니다. 예를 들면 영어 단어에서 음차한 싸인(Sign)이라는 표현이 있는데 '싸인하다'나 '싸인-드리다'처럼 쓸 수 있어요. 또 이 접사가 빈도 높게 쓰이는 축하, 인사, 방문, 감사, 소개, 질문, 답변, 연락, 당부, 부탁, 기도, 공양, 불공 따위도 전부 한자어(중국말 유래)에요.

Comment: 그리고 아래에 다른 분이 답변으로 언급하신 '마중하다'를 보고 생각해 봤는데 동사격의 토박이말은 그 자체가 어근이기 때문에 굳이 '-하다'나 '-드리다' 접사가 붙여 쓰이는 경우가 잘 없는 것으로 보입니다. 이를 테면 '마중하다'는 그 자체가 어근이지 여기서 논하고 있는 '-하다' 접사가 '마중'에 뒤따라 붙은 말이 아닙니다. 하다, 하다, 동음(同音)이라 헷갈릴 뿐 문법적으로 격이든지 품이든지 하는 것이 달라요. 이런 것들을 명사형으로 바꾼 뒤 '-하다'나 '-드리다' 접사를 붙이면 당연히 이상합니다. '마중함하다', '맞이함하다', '섬김하다', '다룸하다', '마중드리다', '맞이드리다', '섬김드리다', '다룸드리다' 이렇게 안 쓰는 이유는 소위의 어댑터가 없어도 이미 그 말 자체가 토박이말과 호환되는 여러가지 변용 표현을 지원하고 있기 때문이에요.

Comment: So basically he's saying: “환영하다” is not a “_behavioral verb_ (동작성을 띠는 동사)” (“to welcome”), rather, it's a “_stative verb_,” a verb describing a state ― “to be welcoming.” You may welcome someone politely, yet you don't “**be**” welcoming politely. ― “A ‘**verb**,’ from the Latin ‘verbum’ meaning ‘word,’ is a word (part of speech) that in syntax conveys **an action** (bring, read, walk, run, learn), **an occurrence** (happen, become), or **a state of being** (be, exist, stand).” from _Wikipedia_.

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to say "환영드립니다" because Koreans are *highly unlikely* to use -드리다 with 환영. I mean 환영드립니다 is *not an idiomatic usage* of the suffix -드리다. You will find that *few* people use 환영드립니다 when you google 환영합니다 (about 52,700,000 results) and 환영드립니다 (7490 results).

---

I think that it is good to understand how other -드리다 examples have been regarded. I would mention 축하드립니다 and 감사드립니다 here.

About a decade ago, my old teachers said, "'축하드립니다' and '감사드립니다' are incorrect because you cannot give and offer 축하 and 감사 to others." I have found that [this post](http://blog.aladin.co.kr/hbooks/popup/7621682) agrees with their logic. The author says:

> ... 국립국어원에서는 2012년부터 ‘감사드리다’를 표준말로 받아들입니다. 관용구이지만 ‘널리 써서 굳어진 말씨’라고 여겨서 표준말로 삼은 셈입니다. 그러나, ‘감사’는 ‘내가 고맙게 느끼거나 여긴다’는 뜻이니, ‘감사’를 ‘드릴’ 수 없습니다. ...

For 축하드리다, [another post](https://happien.tistory.com/348) says:

> 과거의 표준 화법 해설(1992)에서는 ‘축하드리다’가 불필요한 공대라 하여 ‘축하합니다’로만 쓰도록 했으나, 2011년에 개정된 표준 언어 예절에서는 ‘축하합니다’와 함께 높임을 더욱 분명히 드러낸 ‘축하드립니다’도 쓸 수 있는 표현으로 인정하였습니다. ...

As you may have noticed, 감사드리다 and 축하드리다 became accepted as standard seven or eight years ago because they had been commonly used. Nevertheless, googling 감사합니다 (about 153,000,000 results), 감사드립니다 (about 30,100,000 results), 축하합니다 (about 13,300,000 results), and 축하드립니다 (about 7,610,000 results) gives a hint that people still prefer 감사합니다 and 축하합니다.

A verb, 드리다, is defined in the standard dictionary as the following:

> 1. ‘주다’의 높임말.
> 2. 윗사람에게 그 사람을 높여 말이나, 인사, 부탁, 약속, 축하 따위를 하다.
> 3. 신에게 비는 일을 하다.

The second and third meanings relate to the suffix, -드리다.

The standard dictionary has the grammatical information for the suffix, -드리다: "**몇몇** 명사 뒤에 붙어." It implies that you cannot choose whatever noun you want to use and only common usages are allowed. 환영드리다 is not idiomatic for now.

Answer (score 0):

[(국립국어원)](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do;front=55ECA069FD3AAA8DA6F767577E857D56?mn_id=61&qna_seq=121314&pageIndex=2)

'환영합니다'로 표현하는 것이 바릅니다.

'-드리다'는 ‘공손한 행위’의 뜻을 더하는 접미사이므로 '환영드립니다'라는 표현은 의미상 적절하지 않습니다.

---

((몇몇 명사 뒤에 붙어))
‘공손한 행위’의 뜻을 더하고 동사를 만드는 접미사.

¶ 공양드리다/불공드리다/말씀드리다.

Comment: I already found that page, but didn't understand it.

Comment: 국립국어원 loves to say expression A is wrong and B is right, but the rationale they supply is rarely any better than "because I say so." (Well, at least in this instance, I think "환영드립니다" sounds rather awkward.  But I don't think the reason supplied by 국립국어원 makes much sense.)

Answer (score 0):

you can not use 환영드립니다.
cause 축하드립니다.`s actuall word(기본형) is 축하드리다. and 축하드리다. is 높임말.
but 환영is already a 높임말, so you are using 높임말 twice.

Comment: Do you have links to any references that show that this is the actual reason?

Answer (score 0):

(환영 드립니다 = 누군가에게 환영을 드리는 것 = giving a welcome to someone?) it just doesn't make sense.
In 28 years of listening I've never once noticed anyone saying 환영드립니다.
Anyway.. I asked some friends and I had an answer.

Here >

환영드립니다  X

환영 드립니다  X

환영합니다  O

▶'환영드립니다'는 잘못된 표현입니다.

'드리다'는 '동사'로서는 「'주다'의 높임말」,

「윗사람에게 그 사람을 높여 말이나, 인사, 부탁, 약속, 축하 따위를 하다」, 「신에게 비는 일을 하다」라는 뜻이며

'보조 동사'로서는 「(동사 뒤에서 '-어 드리다' 구성으로 쓰여) '주다'의 높임말」입니다.

또한 '-드리다'는 「(몇몇 명사 뒤에 붙어) '공손한 행위'의 뜻을 더하고 동사를 만드는 접미사」입니다.

**

> ★★ 여기서 '환영'은 '오는 사람을 기쁜 마음으로 반갑게 맞음'이란 뜻으로
>   '환영드리다'는 '오는 사람을 기쁜 마음으로 반갑게
>   맞음을 드립니다'가 되기 때문에
>   '환영드립니다'라는 표현은 어법에 맞지 않습니다.

**

한편 '환영합니다'는 기본형이 '(동사) 환영하다/오는 사람을 기쁜 마음으로 반갑게 맞다'로, 적절한 표현입니다.

'환영합니다'에서의 '-ㅂ니다'는 「합쇼(상대 높임법의 하나 *같은 말 ☞ 하십시오체)할 자리에 쓰여,

현재 계속되는 동작이나 상태를 그대로 나타내는 종결 어미」입니다.

Comment: I personally don't get it. Why not _give_ a nice greeting to someone else? I know “환영드립니다” sounds off, but I can't quite grasp why it doesn't work. It's the suffix “-드리다” and it adds politeness to a verb as says your answer. Alright, then why can't we _welcome_ someone _politely_?

Answer (score 0):

**축하** is a kind of 인사 greeting. We use 인사 드립니다 (I give a
greeting) so that we have 축하드린다.

**마중** greeting

1) 제가 마중 나가겠습니다 I'll come to meet you.

2) 공항에서 그의 마중을 받다. He come to an airport to welcome me.

3) 손님 맞이 reception of guests

@ 그 분이 우리를 기쁘게 맞이해 주셨다 He welcomes us. Here 맞이 or
마중 can be replaced with 환영. 환영 is a kind of 마중.

@@ Note that there are 맞이해 주께, 공격해 주께 (I will greet you, I
will attack you), but there is no expression 마중 드린다, 공격
드려요.

Here 맞이 or 공격 is close to receive than give. The goal of
attacking is to obtain something.

손님을 맞아 집으로 들였다 We meet the guest and let him into our
house.