# Is "열심히 일할 것을 약속 드리겠습니다" correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have a sentence as follow:

> 연세 여행사에서 저에게 기회를 주시면 열심히 일할 것을 약속 드리겠습니다.

I think "열심히 일할 것을 약속 드리겠습니다" is not correct, because as i know, following 을/를 must be a verb, not a noun like 약속, so the correct sentence must be "열심히 일할 것을 약속해 드리겠습니다.", right?

Comment: Related (suffix -드리다): https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/3076/2162    It must be 약속드리겠습니다 not 약속 드리겠습니다, but I would say that 약속합니다 is far better.

Comment: 기회를 주신다면 열심히 일할 것을 약속드리겠습니다. is the natural sentence I can make. If the context is clear, 연세 여행사 or 저에게 is not needed.

Comment: If you want to state, '귀사' or '귀 여행사' is more natural and polite than '연세 여행사'. refer to : https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koen/a677ec618d684d95965790efa5a5e28f https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koen/bd0c2a74d37b47a6a8575205b47b9303

Comment: I agree with @dust05, but this does not mean that the example sentence sounds impolite. It is totally fine.

Comment: @user67275 Yeah. It just sounds a bit verbose to specify the name of the company. Just like saying “The Coca-Cola company” instead of “Your company.”

Answer (score 1):

I think both of them don't use often in Korea.
As I am Korean people, many Korean people use “기회를 주신다면 열심히 일하겠습니다”.
(if you give me a chance, I will work hard.) In fact, many Korean doesn't say "연세 여행사" in this sentence. I hope you understand this^^

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is fine if it is for an email or letter.
It might sound a bit too formal for a spoken sentence though.

As for 약속드리겠습니다 versus 약속해 드리겠습니다, I would prefer 약속드리겠습니다. They both mean the same thing, but 약속드리겠습니다 (or 약속드립니다) seems much more common.  -을/를 약속드리다 is used idiomatically in formal contexts.

There was a comment about using 귀사 or 귀 여행사 instead of 연세 여행사 but these 귀- expressions are really old-fashioned and formal.  I think using the name of the company as you did is more in line with recent trends.